# Find current count and total count from string using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string that contains a lot of information, including a total count and current count. I want to use regex and php to match either `[001/100]` or `(001/100)`.

- It can either be wrapped in parentheses or brackets.
- It may also contain spaces inside the parentheses or brackets `( 001/100)`.
- The delimiter can also be a `:` or `|`.

I want to ignore all spaces within the parentheses or brackets and the numbers can be any digets.

I plan to use preg_match_all. I am just struggling to figure out the regex.

```
preg_match_all('/[\(\[](\d+)[\:\|](\d+)[\)\]]/' $tmp, $matches);
```

Comment: `lot of information` is rather ambiguous

Comment: Yes, does that effect things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you but allows mixing parentheses and square brackets.

```
[([]\s*(\d+)\s*[/:|]\s*(\d+)\s*[)\]]
```

Comment: `No ending matching delimiter` Error?

Comment: I have never ever written a single line of PHP - just assuming this rather simple expression will work with all common implementations. Tested it with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Comment: The trick in PHP (and also others) is to quote the slash, when used as delimiter: `/[([]\s*(\d+)\s*[\/:|]\s*(\d+)\s*[)\]]/` (mind the backslash before the slash)

Comment: So you just put slashes at both ends? Like (double) quotes as string delimiters in other languages? I noticed that extra backslash but don't really get what it is for. There still seem to be single quotes as string delimiters in PHP. I will look it up later. Or is it just a PHP-WtF?!? without sense?

Comment: With @DioF comment, I was able to get it working. Thank you both!

Comment: DioF, it's often clearer if you use a non-slash delimiter if the pattern contains slashes. @DanielBrückner, quotes are string delimiters in PHP. Inside the quotes, *pattern delimiters* are needed at either end of the *pattern*, after which can be placed *pattern modifiers* (for case-insensitivity and the like) within the string.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that's the reasoning behind that. So I could write `'@[0-9]+@<but-some-modifiers-here>'` to match integers using `@` as pattern delimiter, right? And obviously I would have to escape `@`s inside the pattern. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: See [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [PCRE Patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) and [Delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: They should have introduced a separate parameter for the modifiers and would have gotten away without the pattern delimiters and the additional escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('@
   [([] #open paren or brace
   \s* #0 or more spaces
   (\d+) #capture the first number
   \s*
   [:/|] #delimeter
   \s*
   (\d+) #capture the second number
   \s*
   [)\]] #capture the closing paren or brace
@x', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: @ATLChris shouldn't have used slash as a delimiter